# Passing a perl array to C++ in SWIG

Tags: c++, arrays, perl, swig

I am using SWIG to interface between a bunch of functions written in perl to a C++ library.

There is a data structure named Polygons which is an array of of type Polygon in perl. Each Polygon is an array of ints (numbers( with x locations on the even positions and y locations in the odd positions. I want to pass this array directly to a C++ function and extract the Polygons and their vertex locations using SWIG.

The easier way would be to extract the vertex locations of each Polygon and pass it to C++. But that would make the interaction between C++ and perl very inefficient and the runtime longer.

But I am not sure how to access the memory when I pass a Polygons object to C++. Since it is in C++, the type checking might cause an error. So I'm looking to see how I can access each Polygon object and it's vertex locations in C++, if I pass the whole array of Polygons from Perl to C++